# Nuget - How to use configSource and Add-BindingRedirect

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, app-config

Is there a way to move `assemblyBinding` element of `app.config` to external file and update it using `Add-BindingRedirect` in Package Manager Console in Visual Studio?

This is my external file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

This is my app.config fragment referencing the file:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding configSource="runtime.config" />
</runtime>
```

This is the `app.config` file after running `Add-BindingRedirect` in Package Manager Console:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding configSource="runtime.config" />
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could not add the  element to an external file with Add-BindingRedirect in Package Manager Console. Because Add-BindingRedirect used to *examines all assemblies within the output path for a project and adds **binding redirects to the `app.config` or `web.config`** where necessary.*

Please refer to the define for Add-BindingRedirect:
http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference

And the configSource attribute are used with a external config file to add some configurations for project. In other words, they are two different ways help us implement bind redirect. So we could not mixed use them together.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, though I'm not sold on the argument that mixing Add-BindingRedirect and configSource is impossible. What if nuget just followed the reference and changed target file?

Comment: If there are different version of nuget reference added in your project, when you run Add-BindingRedirect command, it will add the redirect information into your app.config/web.config automatically.

Comment: Ugh, I really want this functionality.